# Customizing Autofac Controller registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am trying to use Autofac and Autofac.Integrations.Web to register ASP.NET MVC controllers. I am currently using assembly scanning to find the controllers but one of them needs a special parameter that I would prefer to pass in instead. Found below are the registrations I have tried.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// so far I have tried
builder.Register<SpecialController>(c =>
   new SpecialController(wierdParam, c.Resolve<IDependency>())
).Named<SpecialController>("controller.special")
.As<SpecialController>().As<IController>();            

/* And this
builder.Register<SpecialController>(c => 
    new SpecialController(url, c.Resolve<IDependency>())
);            
*/

/* plus this
builder.Register<SpecialController>(c =>
   new SpecialController(url, c.Resolve<IDependency>())
).Named<SpecialController>("controller.special");            
*/
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a registration that worked after some tinkering and mucking with the debugger.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();            

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.Register<IController>(c =>
    new SpecialController(weirdParam, c.Resolve<IDependency>())
).Named<IController>("controller.special");
```

This works because Autofac automatically registers different controllers as hidden named registrations of the type `IController`.

Comment: Glad you found it, perhaps we should add an extension to simplify this kind of override- I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful tool. It was phenomenally easy to get up and running. Even if you do not add this as an extension you probably could consider adding it to the MVC/Web integration wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  withParameter if u want to pass any class object

E.g:

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingsRepository>().As<IApplicationSettingsRepository>()
            .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(NameValueCollection), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings))
```